# regex for Ansible replace module?

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to disable my default /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo files by setting the line

```
enabled=1
```

to

```
enabled=0
```

Easy enough with Ansible's replace module. However, some *.repo files have

```
enabled=1
```

while some have

```
enabled = 1
```

that is, some have no space on each side of the = sign, while others have. What should the regex value be in this task to handle both?

```
- name: Disable the existing CentOS repos in /etc/yum.repos.d
  replace:
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/{{ item }}
    regexp: "enabled = 1" ####### What should this be?? ########
   replace: "enabled=0"
  with_items:
  - CentOS-Base.repo
  - CentOS-fasttrack.repo
  - CentOS-Vault.repo
  - CentOS-CR.repo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `regexp` parameter in the replace module uses [Python regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).  All you need to do is add zero or more qualifiers (`*`) for whitespace (`\s`) between the equals sign.

```
- name: Disable the existing CentOS repos in /etc/yum.repos.d
  replace:
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/{{ item }}
    regexp: 'enabled(\s)*=(\s)*1'
    replace: "enabled=0"
  with_items:
  - CentOS-Base.repo
  - CentOS-fasttrack.repo
  - CentOS-Vault.repo
  - CentOS-CR.repo
```